# What is the difference between the hive jdbc client and the hive metastore java api?

Tags: java, api, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I was using hive jdbc but after that I came to know that there is hive metastore java api ([here](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/package-summary.html)) by which you can again connect to hive and manipulate hive database.

But I was wondering that what exactly is the difference between these two ways.

Sorry if asked anything obvious but any information will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Even I want to understand the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as far as I understand there are 2 ways to connect to Hive

1. using hive metastore server, which then connects in the background to a relational db such as mysql for schema manifestation. This runs on port 9083, generally.
2. hive jdbc server, called HiveServer2, which runs on port 10001, generally...

Now, in the earlier editions of hive, hiveserver2 used to be not so stable and in fact it's multi-threading support was also limited. Things have probably improved in that arena, I'd imagine.

So for JDBC api - yes, it would let you communicate using JDBC and sql.

For the metastore connectivity, there appear to be 2 features.

1. to actually run SQL queries - DML
2. to perform DDL operations.

DDL -

for DDL, the metastore APIs come in handy, org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient [HiveMetaStoreClient](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/metastore/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html) class can be utilized for that purpose

DML -

what I have found useful in this regard is the org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/ql/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/Driver.html [hive.ql.Driver](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/ql/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/Driver.html) class
This class has a method called `run()` which lets you execute a SQL statement and get the result back.
for e.g. you can do following

```
Driver driver = new Driver(hiveConf);
HiveMetaStoreClient client = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);
SessionState.start(new CliSessionState(hiveConf));
driver.run("select  * from employee);
// DDL example
client.dropTable(db, table);
```

Answer (score 2):

metastore in hive as the name indicates is a store for hive db's metadata.
This store is usually an RDBMS.
The metastore api supports interacting with the RDBMS to tinker/tweak the metadata and not the actual hive db/data.For normal usage you may never want/have to use these.I would think that these are meant for people working on creating toolsets to work with the metastore and not for normal day to day usage.